# SQL return rows based on 2 factors (Oracle/JPA)

Tags: sql

Lets say a user selects an fkey of 40.  I want to return the rows that match that col1,col2 combination.

```
    Table 1

id       col1     col2     fkey
---      ----     ---    ----
1        A         E      10
2        A         E      20
3        A         E      40
4        B         W      50
5        B         W      99
6        C         E      12
7        C         E      43
```

Result:

```
id       col1     col2     fkey
---      ----     ---    ----
1        A         E      10
2        A         E      20
3        A         E      40
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select c.*
from combos c
where exists (select 1
              from combos c2
              where c2.fkey = 40 and
                    c2.col1 = c.col1 and c2.col2 = c.col2
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SEL * 
FROM table1
WHERE (col1,col2) 
IN (SEL col1, col2 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE fkey = 40)
ORDER BY fkey
;
```

Comment: Forgot to say jpa does not support multiple column IN clauses.